# Удаление элемента в начале массива

Tags: java

А как можно удалить элемент из массива в начале по аналогии с кодом ниже?

```
 public char[] remove(char[] symbols, int index)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++)
            {
                if (i == index)
                {
                    char[] copy = new char[symbols.length-1];
                    System.arraycopy(symbols, 0, copy, 0, i);
                    System.arraycopy(symbols, i+1, copy, i, symbols.length-i-1);
                    return copy;
                }
            }
            return symbols;
        }
```

Comment: Вся эта колбасня из-за неправильного типа данных. Ясно что использовать массив чаров совершенно ни к чему. вы сами создаёте себе все эти неприятности. `"abc".substring(1)` даёт "bc" и незачем заниматься ерундой.

Comment: А for( ... ) тут зачем ?

Просто 

    if (index >= 0 && index < symbols.length) {
        ...
    }

чем не устраивает ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня удаляет:

```
char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
remove(arr, 0); // {'b', 'c'}
```

Или что требуется?

Comment: Почему-то не работает. А можно как-то через `System.arraycopy`?

    k3 = new char[amatr.length-1];
    remove( k3,0);

Comment: k3 = remove(arr, 0)